# Why don't all Jedi have the same accent?

Tags: star-wars

Going strictly by the movies, Anakin was too old to begin training and looked about 8.  The youngest initiates at the Jedi Temple looked more like 5, and out-of-movies info (google search) suggests that future Jedi are raised by the Jedi as soon as they are found, which might be soon after birth.

So if all Jedi are growing up together, in common surroundings, in one physical location, why do some of them have different accents?  I understand they could be born all over the Galaxy, but 5 is definitely young enough to adapt to a completely new accent.

Dooku, Windu, Obi-Wan and Anakin all have different accents. (Though I realize why Anakin is a sub-par example)

Comment: Do you have specific different accents you can highlight (which aren't related to species)?

Comment: @DVK Dooku, Windu, Obi-Wan and Anakin all have different accents.  Though I realize why Anakin is a sub-par example.  I couldn't say specifically what the accents are,just that they're clearly different from one another.

Comment: Don't have anything specific from canon, but it bears remembering that they **travel the Galaxy, extensively**, since very early Padawan stage (e.g. see Obi-Wan Kenobi junior EU books), not just sit shut-in in the Jedi Temple till the age of 20 like my stereotype of a Shaolin Monk would do.

Comment: Anakin spent only a small portion of his life at the Temple.

Comment: Also, it's not worth posting as an answer, but following Tolkien's "excuse" of "I'm just translating this old book", it can be stated that what we hear isn't Galactic Basic spoken by the Jedi directly, but its translation into English spoken by the actors portraying them. Who were NOT all raised on Coruscant :)

Comment: Also, doesn't *directly* answer the question **in general**, but Dooku is a special case. He's of extremely high-society birth **and is conscious of it to the extreme**, and therefore his accent very likely is delivberate, in-universe.

Comment: In and out of universe: If you live in a certain area long enough you pick up the local accent, no matter how old you are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Jedi don't spend their entire young lives in the Temple they travel with a Master where needed.

A Disney canon example of this would be the *Kanan: The Last Padawan* comic series.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For an out-of-movie answer, I would say it is simply because the actors were never asked to 'put on' accents. They all use their own accent, with Jackson's being the most prominent in that he is an American whereas most of the Jedi actors are English.

I have always thought of the English accents to be very neutral anyway; I've never really heard any Jedi accents (other than Jackson's) that stuck out in any way as sounding like it did not belong.

In-movie, I would say it is most likely that not all Jedi where raised on Coruscant. I am unsure of how long some of the older Jedi that we see in the movies have been at the temple, or even how long a Jedi would live, but it could be plausible that some of the Jedi who now use the temple on Cosuscant may not have been part of the initiative that now causes all new Jedi who are discovered to be taken to the temple.

Comment: Jackson was trying an English accent in those movies? I think he missed it...

Comment: No, that's what I meant. Most of the Jedi in the prequels are English actors, however Jackson stand out more-so than anyone else as he use his own, America, accent.

Comment: English accents are very neutral?   Well, that's very questionable since everything is relative.   At any rate, Ewan McGregor is Scottish and Alec Guinness is English, so McGregor **was** doing an accent.